# Xsd to allow attribute reference some type

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

I want to define an attribute in such a way, that allow to reference some concrete type. Then I want to generate Java classes from this xsd

In Java class it should look like:

```
public class A {
    private Class<SomeType> myAttribute;
}
```

In xsd like:

```
<complexType name="a">
  <attribute name="myAttribute" type="TYPE_TO_ALLOW_ANOTHER_TYPE_REFERENCING"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="someType"/>
```

And usage in xml should look like:

```
<a myAttribute="someType"/>
```

### UPD: real data

Each markers group has a number of markers. All markers within one markers group must have unique id, but not across all other markers groups.

#### structure.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:s="urn:structure:1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn:structure:1.0"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        jaxb:version="2.0">

    <complexType name="markersGroup" abstract="true">
        <sequence>
            <element name="title" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="marker" type="s:marker" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="marker">
        <sequence>
            <element name="title" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="id" type="string" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

#### another-structure.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:s="urn:structure:1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn:structure:default:1.0"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        jaxb:version="2.0">

    <import namespace="urn:structure:1.0"
            schemaLocation="structure.xsd"/>

    <complexType name="entityActions">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="s:markersGroup"/>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="attributes">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="s:markersGroup"/>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

#### matrix.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:am="urn:matrix:1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn:matrix:1.0"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        jaxb:version="2.0">

    <element name="matrices" type="am:matrices"/>

    <complexType name="matrices">
        <sequence>
            <element name="matrix" type="am:matrix" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="matrix">
        <sequence>
            <element name="marker" type="am:marker" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="marker">
        <sequence>
            <element name="profile" type="am:profile" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="markerId" type="string" use="required"/>
        <attribute name="markersGroupType" type="SOME_TYPE_TO_REFERENCE_ANOTHER_TYPE" use="required"/>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="profile">
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="boolean">
                <attribute name="profile-id" type="string" use="required"/>
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

#### matrix.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:matrices xmlns:a="urn:matrix:1.0"
            xmlns:sd="urn:structure:default:1.0">
    <a:matrix>
        <a:marker markersGroupType="sd:attribute" markerId="view">
            <a:profile profile-id="admin">true</a:profile>
        </a:marker>
        <a:marker markersGroupType="sd:entityActions" markerId="view">
            <a:profile profile-id="admin">true</a:profile>
        </a:marker>
    </a:matrix>
</a:matrices>
```

Comment: Why is xsi:type not the correct answer?

Comment: Because it specifies the type of the attribute/element itself. But I want to get a reference to another type

Comment: Edited question to clarify what is the type of myAttribute field is

Comment: To refer to any global entity in an XSD you need the QName type. But I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. _Why_ do you want to refer to _someType_, if not for the purpose of defining the type of tag a?

Comment: The type of element in my program is ID of that element as well. So in another element I want to refer to that ID. I doesn't want id attribute in someType, because it's need to be specified and existence could not be verified while parsing XML. The QName doesn't fit my needs, because it's parsed to QName type, not actual Class<?>

Comment: Can you give an example using actual data and actual type names, instead of abstract names like 'someType'. Also, please check that you are using the word 'attribute' correctly - bearing in mind that you are talking about an XML document.